# Is there a third-person option on Far Cry Primal PS4?

Tags: far-cry-primal

I am wanting to buy this game, but I know it uses a first-person view. Does the PS4 version support third-person view as well?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer, I'm not sure how the PS4 tag doesn't apply when the question specifically is asking if the PS4 version includes a feature.

Comment: @Vemonus Because there are no differences between platforms

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer just because we know that doesn't mean everyone knows that. The tag usage guidance for the PS4 tag says to use it about console-specific features. Asking if a console-specific feature exists still requires the tag, even if it doesn't actually exist, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @Vemonus Cool, and we're here to correct mistakes

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer are you saying you made a mistake or that I'm making one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there has never been a third-person option for any of the Far Cry games. This is the same in Primal.